# Right to left problems after uploading the site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web-hosting

I have been working on a WordPress site on my local host. Every things was working fine for my right to left language (Arabic). but after I have uploaded the site to the web-hosting server I noticed **ONLY** right to left problems. The layout works fine when I switch to Arabic but some issues happen like:

1. The list numbers goes to the left of the text instead of going to the
   right.
2. Some boxes do not order from right to left.
3. The contact forms floats to the left instead of the right.

Is the problem cause comes from the hosting server (Linux server). And what is the solution for such problem.

Comment: Is this a CSS issue (only asking because you use the term 'float')? The only other option is that check the HTTP headers to see if the page is being sent with the correct charset. The header you need to look at is the `content-type` header. I have not worked with rtl languages before but it sounds like a charset mismatch maybe?

Comment: But everything working fine on my windows localhost. If it's css problem then it should show the same problem on my PC.

Comment: Yes, but your windows host is probably serving the pages in the correct charset.

Comment: Can you please post a url/code that refers to the issue? (url preferred)

Comment: Yes sure this is the [the numbers problem] [link] (http://mawadahfdc.com/?p=177)
and this is the [contact form problem] [link] (http://mawadahfdc.com/?page_id=79)

Comment: You should edit that into the question.

Comment: You really should add your code and not links to the site in question.  Things can change, links can die, and the next person that comes along will have no idea what the issue was in the first place preventing them from benefiting from your question and possible subsequent answer.

Comment: @Buggabill the problem that I don't really know what is the suspicious code that I should post .. maybe I will edit the question after the problem is solved.

Comment: @Buggabill Yes youare right but in this situation it seemed like a hard one to get from just a little bit of code. I asked OP to post links only due to the fact that it could be something like the html tag or floats that are causing it (which probably would not have made it to the post). My only hope is that OP posts the offending code once solved so that other people can view the issue.

Comment: @sabsab Oh.. you said that already haha..

Comment: @MichaelCoxon yeah :D and now I am testing your answer .. I hope you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after viewing your site you are using css `float` to move the text. My suggestion would be to remove the `dir="ltr"` in the html tag as this causes the site to be rendered left-to-right. Use the CSS `direction:rtl` clause instead of floats to set your text.. As I have said in the comments I am not familiar with rtl languages so I can only go on what seems to work when I play with it in my browser.

Comment: direction:rtl is the magic code rather than float: right. Thanks man